# Index Match Excel VBA, Error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a project for my marketing class. I keep getting the following error, and I can't figure out how to resolve it. "Object variable or With block variable not set." Can someone please take a look at this?! It would be super appreciated!

```
    Dim k as Integer
    Dim EndRow As Integer
    Dim lookupRange1 As Range
    Dim lookupRange2 As Range
    Dim lookupValue1 As Integer

    EndRow = Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lookupRange1 = Sheets("Data_Main").Range("C2:C50000")
    lookupRange2 = Sheets("Data_Main").Range("A2:A50000")

    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        For k = 2 To EndRow
           lookupValue1 = Cells(k, 13).Value
    Cells(k, 15).Formula = ".Index(lookupRange1, .Match(lookupValue1, lookupRange2, 0))"
        Next k
    End With
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use following code:

```
    Dim k As Long
    Dim EndRow As Long
    Dim lookupRange1 As Range
    Dim lookupRange2 As Range
    Dim lookupValue1 As Integer

    EndRow = Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set lookupRange1 = Sheets("Data_Main").Range("C2:C50000")
    Set lookupRange2 = Sheets("Data_Main").Range("A2:A50000")

    For k = 2 To EndRow
       lookupValue1 = Cells(k, 13).Value
       Cells(k, 15).Formula = "=Index(" & lookupRange1.Address & ", Match(" & lookupValue1 & ", " & lookupRange2.Address & ", 0))"
    Next k
```

1) since `lookupRange1` and `lookupRange2` are objects, you need to use `Set`

2) your `Cells(k, 15).Formula = "..."` statement was wrong. See correct one in my code

3) for `EndRow` it's better to use `Long` type, because max value of `Integer` is only 32767